Firefox won't work even after reinstalling
I tried to uninstall and reinstall firefox thinking it would fix some bug I had with my microsoft 365 login. Now eventhough firefox seems to be propely installed, I can't open it with the icon, neither through the command line.
I followed the instructions from this post : Removing Firefox in Ubuntu with all add-ons like it never existed (main steps involved sudo apt-get purge firefox and rm -r .mozilla/firefox/ (I got sacred to further delete protected files in /usr/ or /etc/ )
I reinstalled using sudo apt-get install firefox but I get :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version (1:1snap1-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

When I type firefox I get :
Command '/usr/bin/firefox' requires the firefox snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install firefox

But when I snap install firefox I get snap "firefox" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
I tried to restart my computer but I always get stuck. I see the firefox icon on the desktop but it doesn't launch.
Additional informations :
-Output of echo $PATH :
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023b/bin:/home/dsutterlin/.local/bin:/home/dsutterlin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin


There is a an executable file in /usr/bin/firefox
I created a ./mozilla/ file in my /home/ but it's empty
Ubuntu version : 22.04.4

Thanks for the help!

Show the output of echo $PATH on the command line.

I added it in the post!

Close all your terminal windows then reopen them.  Does this resolve the problem?  (Usually this happens with stale PATH data and leftover executable paths the system is aware of until you close and reopen your terminal session etc.)

No still the same problem!

Try removing snap firefox and installing the apt version from Firefox PPA https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

main steps involved sudo apt-get purge firefox and rm -r .mozilla/firefox/ -- That will not work for snap firefox. You followed an old and outdated answer

Remove the snap version doens not work sudo snap remove firefox
error: cannot perform the following tasks:

Remove data for snap "firefox" (4209) (failed to remove snap "firefox" base directory: remove /home/dsutterlin/snap/firefox: directory not empty)


It seems to me that you have the snap version of firefox installed but you tried uninstalling it with apt, both apt and snap are different package managers.
First try
type firefox

if you get an output similar to
firefox is hashed (/snap/bin/firefox) 

it means you have the snap version installed in which case you should use
snap remove firefox

after that run
sudo apt-get purge firefox

to remove any remaining information and then finally to re install try
sudo apt-get install firefox

that should solve the issue

"that should solve the issue" but not entirely - you answer is missing essential elements which will mean that the apt version will eventually be replaced by the Snap again. this is the correct way

@graham please make that a new answer, not as a comment on this answer. As a comment it may never be seen.

Better than that, I have used a dupe close vote on the OP and flagged this answer for the community to consider
